# Distributive function in lisp to merge two lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to create a function in lisp that receives two lists and distributes their values into a new list. I need to get the values of the first list and apply to every element of the second.

For example :

```
(funcA '("A"  "B"  "C") '("D" "E" "F"))
```

And returns something like this:

```
((("A" "B" "C") . "D")
 (("A" "B" "C") . "E")
 (("A" "B" "C") . "F"))
```

The thing is: I'm not able to get the `car` value.

Here is my code:

```
(defun funcA (list1 list2)
  (if (null list1)
      nil
      (if (null list2)
          nil
          (cons (cons (cdr list1) (car list2)) 
                (funcA list1 (cdr list2))))))
```

The function above returns me :

```
((("B" "C") . "D")
 (("B" "C") . "E")
 (("B" "C") . "F"))
```

Comment: You just need `(cons list1 (car list2))` instead of `(cons (cdr list1) ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get the point of the use of the function funcA. but if you say that it should work as follows:

For example :

(funcA '("A" "B" "C") '("D" "E" "F"))

And returns something like this:

((("A" "B" "C") . "D") (("A" "B" "C") . "E") (("A" "B" "C") . "F"))

your code is near to the solution, but you need to remove un lisp procedure like this:

```
CL-USER> (defun funcA (list1 list2)
    (if (null list1 )
        nil
        (if ( null list2)
            nil
        (cons (cons list1 (car list2 )) 
               (funcA list1  (cdr list2))))))

FUNCA

CL-USER> (funcA '("A" "B" "C") '("D" "E" "F"))
((("A" "B" "C") . "D") (("A" "B" "C") . "E") (("A" "B" "C") . "F"))
```

you can see that the last line is equal to what tou want

((("A" "B" "C") . "D") (("A" "B" "C") . "E") (("A" "B" "C") . "F"))

the problem was this expression:

(cons (cons (cdr list1 ) (car list2 )) => should be (cons (cons list1 (car list2 ))

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
(defun funcA (list1 list2)
  (mapcar (lambda (el) (cons list1 el)) list2))
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the loop macro. The "collect" keyword causes loop to zip up the result and return it as a list:

```
(defun funcA (list1 list2)
     (loop for i in list2
        collect (cons list1 i)))
```

Note the placement of list1 and list2 in the above code.

Calling it in this fashion:

```
 (funca '("a" "b" "c") '("d" "e" "f"))
```

Returns:

```
((("a" "b" "c") . "d") (("a" "b" "c") . "e") (("a" "b" "c") . "f"))
```